# Magento Market Place issue with Component Manager

Tags: magento-2.1, marketplace, component-manager

I'm having a issue after an upgrade has been done by my isp.
Since the upgrade i couldn't access Component manager.
After looking on the net i established that i cant ping the magento marketplace through ssh. Upon further digging i established that the access keys is somehow making problems in my Marketplace system config. I recreated the keys and reset the old ones but i keep getting this error

Command "show" failed: [InvalidArgumentException] Package magento/framework not found show [--all] [-i|--installed] [-p|--platform] [-a|--available] [-s|--self] [-N|--name-only] [-P|--path] [-t|--tree] [package] [version]

Im not sure what it could be can someone maybe help me out please

Comment: Is it happening on the terminal? What's the command?

Comment: When i go in the backend of my shop. I click on System Then on the Setup Wizard button. then theres 3 options Component manager, System Upgrade and System Config

Answer (score 0):

Go to the root folder, and run these commands on the terminal and try again:

```
alias mage="php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento"

composer update -vv && composer install &&
chmod -R 777 pub/static/ var/ pub/media/ &&
rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
mage cache:clean &
mage cache:flush &
mage indexer:reindex &
mage setup:upgrade &&
mage setup:static-content:deploy ; mage setup:static-content:deploy -f;
mage setup:db-data:upgrade &&
mage dev:source-theme:deploy &&
chmod -R 777 pub/static/ pub/media/ var/
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Rafael thx a million for the help this is what i got so far

```
> rm -rf var/view_preprocessed/ var/cache/ var/page_cache/ var/tmp/ var/generation/ pub/static/frontend/ ;
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Dependency resolution completed in 0.401 seconds
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package magento/product-community-edition 2.1.5 exists as magento/product-community-edition[2.1.3] but these are rejected by your constraint.
```

And when i try to upgrade to 2.1.5 I also get a error read somewhere that if the installation was done through a cpanel it could cause hassle and you must rather do it through the host. 
I have tried that aswell the host is only updating to 2.1.3

I picked up something intresting when i was installing a extension i didnt know where the files must go so i placed them in root and i had to ovverwrite a file i think i went over the composer.json can u tell me where composer.json is located? Think it could be related to the upgrade issue im having